# Return Array instead of String from JSON

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, json, gson

I'm serializing a form and returning JSON like so

`var dataForm = JSON.stringify($('#form').serializeObject());`

Then in my action class I create a JSON model object using `gson.fromJson()`

`SomeObj so = gson.fromJson(dataForm, SomeObj.class);`

In `SomeObj` I have a `String` array field

```
public class SomeObj {
    private String[] someField;

    public String[] getSomeField() {
        return this.someField;
    }
    public void setSomeField(String[] someField) {
        this.someField = someField;
    }
}
```

I have several checkboxes with the name someField. When multiple checkboxes are selected there will be a json array created and correctly mapped on to the model class

So for example

`{"someField":["someValue1", "someValue2"]}`

The problem is when there is only one checkbox selected the json will look like this

`{"someField":"someValue1"}`

This will generate the below exception, because it's expecting an array instead of a `String`

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING`

Any ideas how to fix this? `someField` is not the only value I'm returning. There are also `Booleans` and `String`s that I omitted

Comment: try - var dataForm = JSON.stringify([$('#form').serializeObject()]);

Comment: There are also other values being returned that should be a string

Comment: So if it has one key=>value it needs to be an array correct? Otherwise it's fine?

Comment: That's right. It is an array on the pojo

Comment: Tom, how is this a duplicate of that other question?

Comment: Ok, take a look at :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
Just make a condition to check if the obj has only one, then use map to convert it into an array.

Comment: instead of an array, cant u use `List`

Comment: Changing the type to List would mean I have to change it in the whole project and it's huge, also not sure if that would work

Comment: Do you use the array name syntax for your html elements? Something like: `<input type="checkbox" name="someField[]"/>`

Comment: Yes, `name="someField"`

Comment: Can you try using square brackets after your field name like I did in my example?

Comment: As another hint: can you point out where the JS function `serializeObject()` comes from? This isn't a default jQuery function, it's probably from some module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a hidden field with an empty value. It's not a very elegant solution and should be a better way but it works

`<input type="hidden" name="someField" value="">`